# Searching GCC version with workable stack protector SSP

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, gentoo, ssp

Using `genkernel all` (on Gentoo) and gcc-5.4.0 get the error:

> -fstack-protector not supported by compiler

I know [starting from 4.8.3 gcc supports SSP](https://www.gentoo.org/support/news-items/2014-06-15-gcc48_ssp.html).

But I have this bug compiling Gentoo kernel. Which gcc version you'll advise?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
genkernel --menuconfig all
```